# qq-form does not upload file to S3 bucket and ignores {request: endpoint}, still returns 200

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader, forms, http-post

I am using FU-5.0.8 on Ubuntu14, apache2 php5.  I successfully created page to drag n drop file, create signature and upload to my AWS S3 bucket.

I then integrated that code into an existing form, using the qq-form. The FU element and the form are generated correctly, I am able to enter data and the data is posted to my DB including the key file name generated by FU.

Issue 1: FU is not pointing to the bucket I have identified in my script.  Instead of the correct bucket as before, it make my domain the target bucket name.

Issue 2: FU provides a progress bar and shows the upload is complete and returns 200.  I don't know how this is possible, do FU check that the file actually exists upon completion?

Here are the standalone upload script and the script with the form.  As you can see they have an identical endpoint.  I have included the POST created from the qq-form where you can see the endpoint is incorrect.

FU in the JSON POST is setting the bucket to www.biggytv.com, which does not exist.  It should got to btv_upload_org.s3.amazonaws.com

You assistance is appreciate.

**FORM CODE**

```
<form action="https://www.biggytv.com/btvChannels/FSsubmit.php" id="qq-form" class="span6">

            <div id="fineuploader-s3" class="span6"></div>
            <div class="form-group span2">
                <label>Program Title</label>
                <input type = "text" class="span4" name="program_title" maxlength="200" autofocus="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group span6">
                <label>Program Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" maxlength="1000" class="span8" id="count_me" placeholder="Please do not include links in the Program Description. Add any links to content on other sites as part of your profile." required></textarea>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group span5">
                <label>Video Language</label>
                <select name="vid_language" class="span4" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                <?php $language->data_seek(0);
                while($language_row = $language->fetch_assoc()){
                $languageid = $language_row['short'];
                $languagename = $language_row['name'];
                    echo "<option value=\"$languageid\">
                        $languagename
                    </option>";
                }?> 
                </select>   
            </div>

            <div class="form-group span5">
                <label>Target Audience</label>
                <select name="Audience_DART1" class="span4" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php $audience->data_seek(0);
                    while($audience_row = $audience->fetch_assoc()){
                    $audienceid = $audience_row['tar_aud_code'];
                    $audiencename = $audience_row['tar_aud_name'];
                        echo "<option value=\"$audienceid\">
                            $audiencename
                        </option>";
                    }?> 
                    </select>   
            </div>


        <div class="form-group span5">
            <label>Genre</label>
            <select name="genre" class="span4" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php $genre->data_seek(0);
                while($genre_row = $genre->fetch_assoc()){
                $genreid = $genre_row['genre_id'];
                $genrename = $genre_row['genre_name'];
                    echo "<option value=\"$genreid\">
                        $genrename
                    </option>";
                }?> 
                </select>   
        </div>
            <div class="form-group span5">
                <label>Rating</label>
                <select name="Rating_DART" class="span4" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php $rating->data_seek(0);
                    while($rating_row = $rating->fetch_assoc()){
                    $dartid = $rating_row['dart_rating'];
                    $dartname = $rating_row['dart_rating_name'];
                        echo "<option value=\"$dartid\">
                            $dartname
                        </option>";
                    }?> 
                    </select>   
            </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="content_owner_name" value=<?php echo $content_owner_name;?>>
                <input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="801102">


            <div class="span6 offset2">
            <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" class="span4">
            </div>
        </form>
```

**QQ-FORM**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
                request: {
                    endpoint: "btv_upload_org.s3.amazonaws.com",

                    accessKey: "XXXXXXXX"
                },

                template: "qq-template",

                signature: {
                    endpoint: "/finesig/"
                },

                forceMultipart: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                debug: true,


                cors: {
                    expected:true,
                    },

                resume: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                objectProperties: {
                    acl: "public-read"
                },

                validation: {
                    itemLimit: 1,
                    sizeLimit: 150000000,
                    acceptFiles: "video/mp4, video/quicktime, video/x-flv, video/x-ms-wmv",
                    allowedExtensions: ["mp4", "mov", "flv", "wmv"],
                },



            })

        });
```

**POST JSON**

```
JSON
conditions
[Object { acl="public-read"}, Object { bucket="www.biggytv.com"}, Object { Content-Type="video/mp4"}, 12 more...]
0
Object { acl="public-read"}
1
Object { bucket="www.biggytv.com"}
2
Object { Content-Type="video/mp4"}
3
Object { success_action_status="200"}
4
Object { key="e001946c-a472-4412-9854-b44fede53e72.mp4"}
5
Object { x-amz-meta-program_title="Marcus%20Johns"}
6
Object { x-amz-meta-description="Marcus%20Johns"}
7
Object { x-amz-meta-vid_language="en"}
8
Object { x-amz-meta-audience_dart1="U"}
9
Object { x-amz-meta-genre="6"}
10
Object { x-amz-meta-rating_dart="G"}
11
Object { x-amz-meta-content_owner_name="MarcusJohns"}
12
Object { x-amz-meta-channel_id="801102"}
13
Object { x-amz-meta-qqfilename="7920637590280230638.mp4"}
14
["content-length-range", "0", "150000000"]
expiration
"2014-10-14T00:11:08.742Z
```

**Uploader Log**

```
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Sending simple upload request for 0
custom.....0.8.js (line 207)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
custom.....0.8.js (line 207)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Sending POST request for 0
custom.....0.8.js (line 207)
POST https://www.biggytv.com/finesig/
200 OK
552ms   
custom.....0.8.js (line 3810)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Sending upload request for 0
custom.....0.8.js (line 207)
POST https://www.biggytv.com/btvChannels/FSsubmit.php
200 OK
938ms   
custom.....0.8.js (line 9849)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Received response status 200 with body: Array
(
    [key] => 05a829e8-bea1-44f6-b35d-1f620f1043af.mp4
    [AWSAccessKeyId] => XXXXXXXXX
    [Content-Type] => video/mp4
    [success_action_status] => 200
    [acl] => public-read
    [x-amz-meta-program_title] => Marcus%20John
    [x-amz-meta-description] => Mar
    [x-amz-meta-vid_language] => en
    [x-amz-meta-audience_dart1] => U
    [x-amz-meta-genre] => 6
    [x-amz-meta-rating_dart] => G
    [x-amz-meta-content_owner_name] => MarcusJohns
    [x-amz-meta-channel_id] => 801102
    [x-amz-meta-qqfilename] => 7920637590280230638.mp4
    [policy] => eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNC0xMC0xNFQwMDozNzoxNS44NjZaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6Ind3dy5iaWdneXR2LmNvbSJ9LHsiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIjoidmlkZW8vbXA0In0seyJzdWNjZXNzX2FjdGlvbl9zdGF0dXMiOiIyMDAifSx7ImtleSI6IjA1YTgyOWU4LWJlYTEtNDRmNi1iMzVkLTFmNjIwZjEwNDNhZi5tcDQifSx7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtcHJvZ3JhbV90aXRsZSI6Ik1hcmN1cyUyMEpvaG4ifSx7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJNYXIifSx7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtdmlkX2xhbmd1YWdlIjoiZW4ifSx7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtYXVkaWVuY2VfZGFydDEiOiJVIn0seyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLWdlbnJlIjoiNiJ9LHsieC1hbXotbWV0YS1yYXRpbmdfZGFydCI6IkcifSx7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtY29udGVudF9vd25lcl9uYW1lIjoiTWFyY3VzSm9obnMifSx7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtY2hhbm5lbF9pZCI6IjgwMTEwMiJ9LHsieC1hbXotbWV0YS1xcWZpbGVuYW1lIjoiNzkyMDYzNzU5MDI4MDIzMDYzOC5tcDQifSxbImNvbnRlbnQtbGVuZ3RoLXJhbmdlIiwiMCIsIjE1MDAwMDAwMCJdXX0=
    [signature] => d48Ibli+V6/RmN3bUUZKVJ0woew=
)


custom.....0.8.js (line 207)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Simple upload request succeeded for 0
```

**Update**

In the FU documentation you referred to "Integrating with existing html forms", the "simple example"  'action' is set to a script not a S3 bucket, that is why I am confused.

However, I have configured my script in the manner of your answer.

When I set the Action to the bucket, the uploadSuccess: {endpoint} POST does not include any of my form data, just key, uuid,name,bucket,etag.

If I set the Action as to https://www.biggytv.com/btvChannels/FSsubmit.php, the form data is sent in the POST and FU returns a 200 that the file was uploaded to www.biggytv.com, a bucket that does not exist.

So my issue is the uploadSuccess: {endpoint} is not including any of my form data in the POST.

Thank you.!

Comment: If the response to the upload is a 200 and the content length is not zero, then the file has been uploaded to the specified destination.  What happens after that is out of the control of fine uploader.  If you want a more detailed response you will need to provide fine uploader logs, request logs, and your fine uploader config code.

Comment: Here is the specific issue:  Using qq-form per the documents I put the destination bucket as the 'action' of the form and uploadSuccess:endpoint as the post destination.

Comment: The file uploads to the required bucket and POST bucket, key, filename, UUID, and etag.  If I set the 'action' to the endpoint post destination I review a POST with all the form data, but the file does not upload.  I would be happy to provide everything requested, where should I send it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the requested info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute in the form serves the same purpose as the `request.endpoint` option. You should leave the `request.endpoint` option off of your JavaScript configuration.  The `action` attribute will define the S3 endpoint where your files will be uploaded.  If you want the file to be sent to "btv_upload_org.s3.amazonaws.com", then that should be the value of the form's `action` attribute.  Again, leave `request.endpoint` off your JavaScript config.

In your JavaScript config, you can (and must) define a [`signature.endpoint` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#signature.endpoint).  Fine Uploader will send a POST to this endpoint to sign each request before a request is sent to the S3 endpoint defined in the `action` attribute.

You may also define an [`uploadSuccess` endpoint](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#uploadSuccess) in your JavaScript config.  Fine Uploader will POST to this location when the file is successfully in S3.

You can find all information regarding form support on the [associated feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/forms.html).

Comment: I have edited my question as there is still an issue.  Thanks!

Comment: The form data is associated with your object in S3.

Comment: Yes, however you can see my confusion from the documentation and response.  So I am clear, if I use the qq-form function, FU will not POST any form data to the uploadSuccess endpoint script.  I have to extract that metadata from the upload file on S3 after it is uploaded, which is different that the FU Traditional integration with existing forms where the POST data will include the form data.Is this on your roadmap?  Thank you very much.

Comment: It's actually consistent with the behavior of the traditional endpoint Uploader.  In both cases, the form data is sent to the upload endpoint.  The upload endpoint in this case happens to be S3.  However it does make sense to also send this data to the uploadSuccess endpoint.  Please [open up a feature request](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) so we can ensure this is part of an upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your assistance and recommendation.